# Is it possible to access JavaScript libraries without needing an internet connection?

Tags: jxbrowser

I just found JxBrowser but could not find an answer. Is it possible to have the underlying HTML reference external sources (images, CSS, JS libraries) from within a JAR, or is it mandatory to access using HTTP?

I work on a complex Java Swing app that is shipped to hundreds of companies, with many thousands of end-users. Requiring an internet connection to be able to access these external resources would be a deal-breaker.

If so, could someone provide a very brief example?

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser allows loading HTML files with images, CSS, and JavaScript libraries from a JAR file included into your Java application classpath. Please take a look at the guide at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000115433-loading-html-from-jar